# In Snap.svg, how to make Element.drag() work only when a particular variable is true

Tags: snap.svg

I have a function like this:-

```
function dragMap(evt){
  if (mousemode == 'pan'){
    Snap('#zoombox').drag(move, start, stop);
  }
}
dragMap();
```

My challenge is when variable mousemode changes to something else, e.g. mousemode == 'simple'

even then the following drag code continues to show its effect on dragging Element(#zoombox).

```
Snap('#zoombox').drag(move, start, stop);
```

I want that dragging shall work/execute **ONLY WHEN variable mousemode is set to 'pan'.**
What should be way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options.

1. Snap('#zoombox').undrag() whenever mousemode changes.
2. Write your own drag handler. There's a couple of examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559349/snap-svg-drag-event-handler). Just add a check for your variable inside the functions.

Comment: Thank You! 
Snap('#zoombox').undrag() whenever mousemode changes. It worked.